# Why does my python dictionary not updating properly?

Tags: python, file-io, google-translate, dictionary

Hello I am trying to store my words I translate using the google api so I don't have to do the same translation twice. So here is my code:

```
def loadtransdict(fro, to):
    try:
        tdictf = open("transdict"+fro+"-"+to+".txt", "r")
        pairs = tdictf.read().split(",")
        tdictf.close()
        tdict = {}
        for pair in pairs:
            tdict[pair.split(":")[0]] = pair.split(":")[1]
        return tdict

    except:
        tdictf = open("transdict"+fro+"-"+to+".txt", "w")
        tdictf.close()
        return {}
    else:
        return None

def writetodict(fro, to, sword, dword):
    try:
        tdictf = open("transdict"+fro+"-"+to+".txt", "r")
        if tdictf.read() == "":
            tdictf = open("transdict"+fro+"-"+to+".txt", "a")
            tdictf.write(sword+":"+dword)
        else:
            tdictf = open("transdict"+fro+"-"+to+".txt", "a")
            tdictf.write(","+sword+":"+dword)
        tdictf.close()
    except:
        return None

def translate(original_word, fro, to):
    tdict = loadtransdict(fro, to)
    if original_word in tdict:
        return tdict[original_word]
    else:
        print original_word
        print tdict
        #mm = requests.get('http://api.mymemory.translated.net/get?q='+word+'&langpair='+fro+'|'+to)
        gt = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=MYKEY='\
                          +original_word+'&source='+fro+'&target='+to+'&prettyprint=false')
        translated_word = re.search("translatedText\":\"(.*)\"", gt.text).group(1)
        writetodict(fro,to,original_word,translated_word)
        return translated_word
```

where transdicten-es.txt is a file containing translations written to it in the following format:

> constantly:constantemente,commanded:ordenado,damp:humedad,mistaken:equivocado,dignity:dignidad

My trouble is that often words that have already been translated end up being translated again, not just retrieved from the dictionary and I cannot work out why! If it helps, translate() is being called many 1000s of times in a row in a for loop. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using `bsddb` instead? It might simplify your program a great deal.

Comment: Check the indentation on your `loadtransdict` method - Python is whitespace sensitive.

Comment: larsmans: I'll look into bsddb, this way of doing it does seem a little clunky, but I was just prototyping and was confused as to why this didn't work. Thanks though.
thegrinner: That is an artifact of copy-pasting from eclipse, the code runs fine. Will edit to avoid confusion.

Comment: you should never ever do `except:` because 'No Error should pass silently'. Just do `except ():` and fill the brackets with the errors when they occur. I think then you may find the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your bare except clauses will hide each and any exception, so you just don't now what really happens in your code. As a rule of thumb: *never* use bare except clauses, only catch the exceptions you expect AND can handle - or at least log exceptions one way or another and never do anything potentially harmful assuming you know what happened when you don't. In your case, `loadtransdict` should not create an empty file, but it should definitly mention something went wrong:

```
def loadtransdict(fro, to):
    tdict = {}
    filename = "transdict"+fro+"-"+to+".txt"
    try:
        tdictf = open(filename, , "r")
        data = tdictf.read()
        tdictf.close()
    except Exception, e:
        print "failed to open '%s'for reading : %s" % (filename, e)

    else:
        pairs = data.split(",")
        for pair in pairs:
            tdict[pair.split(":")[0]] = pair.split(":")[1]

    return tdict

def writetodict(fro, to, sword, dword):
    filename = "transdict"+fro+"-"+to+".txt"
    try:
        tdictf = open(filename, "rw")
    except Exception, e:
        print "failed to open '%s'for read/write : %s" % (filename, e)
        return False

    data = tdictf.read().strip()
    sep = "," if data else ""
    tdictf.write(data + sep + sword + ":" + dword)
    tdictf.close()
    return True
```

This might not solve the root cause by itself but you should had least get a clue about what went wrong.

Comment: What did you mean @bruno by tdictf = `open(filename, "rw")` which python mode should I use?

Comment: You don't need `try-except-finally` blocks when dealing with files. [Use `with` instead.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)